# NodeJS + Nginx 403 Forbidden but URL:PORT is working

Tags: dns, port-forwarding, ssl, nginx, node.js

I have a NODEJS website on production and I can't access to :

https://mydomain1.com   =>   403 Forbidden
https://mydomain1.com:443 => 403 Forbidden

But everything is working when I add port ":8080" at the end :

https://mydomain1.com:8080   =>   Success! I can go everywhere on my website

I don't know why I'm forbidden on root and not on port 8080 where my app is running ?

file "default" on /etc/nginx/site-available
(same as file "default" on /etc/nginx/site-enable).

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl default_server;
        listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name mydomain1.com;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
}


server {
    if ($host = mydomain1.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

    server_name mydomain1.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Nginx error.log :

```
2021/04/29 09:29:16 [error] 6136#6136: *6 access forbidden by rule, client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: mydomain1.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "mydomain1.com"
```

P.S : I added certificat SSL with Certbot this morning, it change my nginx.conf a little bit but no change; I still need to add ":8080" to my url to access my website and when I remove ":8080" I cant access anything. Please help me ?

Edit : Here my NODEJS website :

```
//================= TSL ==========================
const https = require('https');
var tls = require('tls')
var fs = require('fs')

const SSLoptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
};

let serverHttps = https.createServer(SSLoptions, app).listen(8080)
```

If I delete "default" on /etc/nginx/site-enable to only keep "default" at /etc/nginx/site-available I have "site not available" on mydomain1.com but mydomain1:8080 still works the same.

Comment: First off: Please properly format your `nginx.conf`. // You say you can access it on port 8080 using HTTPS but NGINX tries to use HTTP. Is that correct? // Your application should not be accessible from the outside on port 8080.

Comment: Yes I can only access it with port 8080 on my URL

Comment: Again: One is HTTPS, one is HTTP. They are not interchangeable. Please make sure your configuration is correct and your question does not contain an error.

Comment: I added my NODEJS website port listening. Do you advice me to make a website on a port HTTPS + HTTP ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about website administration, I don't run one, but from my limited knowledge I know HTTPS protocol uses port 443 by default, and if the port number isn't specified then the default port is assumed, so it appears that when you try to access https://mydomain1.com you are actually trying to access https://mydomain1.com:443, which isn't open.

To verify, just try to access https://mydomain1.com:443 and if you get the same 403 Forbidden error then that's the case.

Your port 443 isn't open and your website runs on port 8080, so you have to use domain name + port number to access your website, because you website isn't on the default port which is assumed by browsers.

So I suggest you to change your website to make it run on port 443, the your problem will be solved.

Comment: Port 443 _is_ open. That’s what NGINX is there for.

Comment: I don't want to run my app port 443 because I need root access and it's a security concern. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: By the way, mydomain1.com:443 send 403 Error like any other port than 8080 where my app is running... But if it's the only way